# Merge and Duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this Address table which has multiple columns. I want to concatenate the street number and street name column as Address and check if the address is unique.

```
SELECT ( street_num + ' ' + street_name ) AS Addr 
FROM  [propertyaddress_workfinal] AS t1 
      INNER JOIN (SELECT ( street_num + ' ' + street_name ) AS A2 
                  FROM  [propertyaddress_workfinal]) AS t2 
              ON t1.addr = t2.a2 
WHERE  Count(*) > 1
```

I get and error stating invalid column name 'Addr'.

Doing something silly here.

Comment: Does PropertyAddress_Workfinal have column called `Addr`? If not, then that's your problem. You can't refer the column you created with t1.Addr.

Comment: Then how do I refer a column created in the 'Select' clause in a join. I need the column Addr as a concatenation of two columns Street name and Street Num

Comment: And when you fix that you'll find you can't reference `count` in `where` and are missing a `group by`. You don't need the self join anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way to do it

```
SELECT street_num + ' ' + street_name AS Addr 
FROM  [propertyaddress_workfinal]
GROUP BY street_num + ' ' + street_name
HAVING Count(*) > 1
```

Though if the concatenated space isn't integral to your duplicate matching

```
GROUP BY street_num, street_name
```

Will perform better if you have a composite index on those two columns.